# What is the purpose of 'duplicate' jQuery pseudo-class selectors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

Using the [pseudo-class selector](https://api.jquery.com/password-selector/)

```
$( "input:password" )
```

seems to be an equivalent and yet likely slower version of

```
$( 'input[type="password"]' )
```

(Slower because, as noted in the doc linked, "`:password` is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, so queries using `:password` cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM `querySelectorAll()` method.")

That gives rise to the question: is there a stated reason why this pseudo-class selector exists?  What potential advantages does it offer, if any?  In what cases would there be a difference in behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`:password`](https://api.jquery.com/password-selector/) is really only useful in the jQuery API for symmetry/completeness, since it's exactly the same as `[type=password]`.

But [`:text`](https://api.jquery.com/text-selector/) isn't just the same as `[type=text]`, because it also matches `input` elements that don't have a `type` attribute (and so are treated as `type="text"` by the browser). `[type=text]` wouldn't do that. You'd have to use `input[type=text]` combined with `input:not([type])`.

Similarly, [`:button`](https://api.jquery.com/button-selector/) isn't just `input[type=button]`, it also matches `button` elements.

Similarly, [`:input`](https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) isn't just a synonym for `input`, it matches `input`, `textarea`, `select`, and `button` elements.

So in the general case, the purpose of them is to help programmers not forget to include things they probably meant to include (like `input` elements without a `type`) and/or conciseness.

Looping back around to `:password`, it's just there for symmetry.

Comment: Personally, I've never cared for them. :-)

Comment: Well, it seems like everything _except_ `:password` does in fact have some behavioral difference, with their purpose being to account for an everyday user's idea of what that "thing" is, such as a button being either literal `<button>` or `<input type='button'>`

Comment: Some were added as a polyfill because some or all browsers had not implemented the CSS selector yet while others predate CSS3 selectors and were the influence for some of the new native selectors that are in modern browsers.

Comment: Note that these have been deprecated and should not be used (use the `.filter()` method if you really need them). Since most modern browsers now support the majority of CSS3 selectors, the Sizzle JS selector engine is being sunset and will be removed in a future version which means the jQuery-specific pseudo-classes will no longer function.

Comment: @Jim - None of these is a polyfill, they're not standard CSS at all. They're also not deprecated, at least not according to the API documentation linked above. Citation for Sizzle being removed from jQuery? As opposed to some variant/"slim" version?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Not the ones you listed, there are [more](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). I know `:even` and `:odd` were added quite a while back. `:nth-child` was added before most browsers suppored it and `:has` is a CSS4 selector and not supported by any browser yet.

Comment: Right. The question was about `:password`, though.